# DataTable horizontal scrollbar to appear like the window scroll -x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables-1.10

I have a dataTable where in the horizontal scrollbar appears only when I vertically scroll down to the end of the table. I want the X-scrollbar to appear without the need to scroll down. I did try setting a fixed height to the dataTable and using a window resize,that did not work right for me.

For example in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremysouthard/sg8o8vpv/1/), When I make the window smaller,I have to go to the end of the table to scroll horizontally.

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "fixedColumns": {
           "leftColumns": 2,
        },
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "fixedHeader": true,
    } );
```

Is there a way to solve this?Please suggest!

Thank you!

Comment: If you set the width of the entire page to have room for the datatable, the scroll will appear if needed at the bottom of the browser. Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the FixedHeader only appears when you scroll down. You can see this in devtools.
"Use 'FixedHeader' for column fixing when scrolling is not enabled")" - see https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: this makes the header Fixed, what I am looking for is-> If a datatable has many rows, I have to scroll vertically all the way down to scroll through the columns. So I am looking for a way to have the horizontal scroll bar of the datatable as the horizontal scroll of the whole screen. Can this be done?